# How can I open a file, replace a string in that file and write it to a new file using Python

Tags: python, string, file, replace

I have written this small script to open a file iterate through a list and create new files based on the names in the list "hostnames.txt". Now I need to be able to read a seperate file we will call "template" and search through and replace the word "hostname" with the actually hostnames acquired from the "Hostnames.txt" file.Then output the files with that hostname actually in the new file that was created. Also upon creating the files it adds a "?" at the end of the hostname before adding the ".test" and I don't know where it's coming from.

```
import sys
input_file = open ('hostnames.txt', 'r')
template = open ('hosttemplate.txt', 'r')
count_lines = 0
for hostname in input_file:
        system = hostname
        computername = open(system.strip()+".test",'a')
        computername.write("need to write data from template to file and replace the string hostname with the hostname from hostnames.txt")
        print hostname
        count_lines += 1
print 'number of lines:', count_lines
```

Comment: Are you sure it is a `?` and not just an unprintable character?  How are you looking at the file, a text editor, or what?  Does the file come from another operating system?

Comment: The `?` is probably a newline character, at least that's how it shows up in `ls` and the like.  If you iterate of the lines of a text file, the trailing newline is part of the line string. Try with `system = hostname.strip()`. Additional note: Are the contents of the `hostnames.txt` trusted?

Comment: Yes they are trusted it is a file list i personally created based on needed data. It is actually a list of "hostnames" that I compiled to create the files from.

Comment: how do you choose which hostname should go where?

Comment: in my template file I used the word "hostname" I need to iterate through 2 files and take data from both and place it in one "new file" .

Comment: So for example I want to scan through a file called "template" searching for the word "hostname" and replace it with the actual "hostname" that is collected from "hostnames.txt" and write it to a new file that begins with the "hostname"+.test. so now I have a multitude of new files named hostname.test that have ALL the data from Template.txt and the "hostname" replaced.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
input_file = open ('hostnames.txt', 'r')
template = open ('hosttemplate.txt', 'r')
tdata = template.readlines()
count_lines = 0
for hostname in input_file:
        system = hostname.strip()
        computername = open(system+".test",'a')
        for line in tdata:
            computername.write(line.replace('hostname', system))
        computername.close()
        print hostname
        count_lines += 1
print 'number of lines:', count_lines
```

Before the loop, we open hostnames.txt and read the contents of hosttemplate.txt into list tdata.

As we step through hostnames.txt ("for hostname in input_file"), we

- strip the newline off hostname before assigning to system,
- open the file .test with handle computername
- iterate through tdata, writing each line to computername after replacing the string 'hostname' with the actual name of the host (system)
- close the file open through handle computername
- print the hostname and increment count_lines